# Finding text from HTML in original markdown

Tags: javascript, html, markdown, text-processing

I am trying to add content to a piece of markdown based on selected text. The problem is that the selected text has been converted to HTML so I am not sure how to find the position of the selected text in the original markdown. Is there an algorithm I can use to do this?

Example (using | as the selection carets):

Original markdown:

```
Heading
=======

##Heading 2
####Heading 4
```

Processed HTML:

```
<h1>Heading</h1>
<h2>H|eading 2|</h2>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
```

Desired result:

```
Heading
=======

##H|eading 2|
####Heading 4
```

Is there an algorithm that can convert an arbitrary selection in the processed HTML (e.g. |Head|ing or H|ead|ing 4) into a position in the original markdown?

Comment: Defined **has been processed**. The original `.md` is just a text file, which you should be able to match strings using regular expression or `find` and `sed` using shell's command line. If you mean finding and replacing the processed HTML, you can use something like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: The markdown has been converted to HTML. I would like some javascript to convert the position of text in the HTML to the position in the original markdown. Because punctuation etc has been removed between words (e.g. for a markdown list) it's not a straight regex match.

Comment: would you consider editing to include more code and make your problem clearer?

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear. Basically, I can have any arbitrary markdown and processed HTML, and I want to convert the position of a selection in the processed HTML into the equivalent position in the original.

Answer (score 0):

`[^#{2}H{1}]*[2]$` will match `eading 2` in your example. It's a quick and dirty regex just to match your sample string only.

Here is how you match `eading 2` in your sample HTML:

```
var text = '';
var re = /[H{1}]*[2]$/;
var myRe = /[^H{1}]*[2]$/;

var elements = document.getElementByTagName('h2');

for(var elm in elements) {
   // no match to 'Heading 2', keep searching
   if(re.match(elements[h2].innerHTML) == null) {
     continue;
   } else {
     // when found, match only 'eading 2'
     text = myRe.match(elements[h2].innerHTML);
   }
}
```

To match a string in Markdown

```
var re = /[^#{2}H{1}]*[2]$/;
```

Hope it helps.